# Webpage not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have added 31 buttons on web page and 30 of them are either "Yes" or "No" or "NO Clue"and last is "Submit". I have used jquery functions such that "NO" and "NO Clue" fades out on clicking "YES" and viceversa. But since my input type = "submit" for all, my jquery is not working as the page reloads after clicking the very first button. Any suggestions on how to implement this ? I am a noob so please go easy on me.

Comment: Change the type to `type="button"` and add `click` handlers to save the state of all answers.

Comment: It would help if you were to include the code with the question, do you have it available to paste in?

Comment: have your buttons type as button why you have it as submit?

Comment: Use <Button> Tag for the 30 buttons , and use one submit button. Or add a class to all the Yes, No , May B Buttons and use an ID for the submit button.

Answer (score 4):

Make your "yes/no/no clue" buttons html buttons elements

```
<button type="button">No</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the buttons like so:

```
<button type="button">Yes</button>
<button type="button">No</button>
<button type="button">No Clue</button>
<!-- include the rest of the buttons here -->
<input type="submit" value="Submit!">
```

The buttons are elements on the page which can be clicked, whereas the submit input element type will try to 'submit' (or send) the values of elements back to the server.

Answer (score 0):

If the "Yes", "No" and "No Clue" buttons have a `submit` type then they will submit the form and the page would be reloaded. Try using a `button` type for them.